# How to retrieve Active Directory group policy maximum password age using LDAP

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

I would like to retrieve the group policy regarding to passwords from the company Active Directory, but I cannot find any info, how to filter my search to find the attributes.

At first I like to get the maximum password age, which should be the `msDS-MaximumPasswordAge` attribute.

The search term I've been trying:

```
ldap_search($ldap, 'CN=Policies,CN=System,DC=company,DC=com', '(objectClass=*)', array('msDS-MaximumPasswordAge'));
```

This is the widest filter I've tried, but it returns no object where the count is not zero. Of course I replaced the DC name for the purpose of this example.

Did I missed something? Should I search under a different container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you have implemented a Group Policy with msDS-PasswordSettings enabled?

You should use a filter like (&(objectClass=msDS-PasswordSettings))

And return an attribute "msDS-MaximumPasswordAge".

A msDS-PasswordSettings entry appears in an LDIF like:

```
dn: CN=PS??,CN=Password Settings Container,CN=System,DC=dc1,DC=contoso,DC=com
objectClass: msDS-PasswordSettings
msDS-MaximumPasswordAge:-1728000000000
msDS-MinimumPasswordAge:-864000000000
msDS-MinimumPasswordLength:8
msDS-PasswordHistoryLength:24
msDS-PasswordComplexityEnabled:TRUE
msDS-PasswordReversibleEncryptionEnabled:FALSE
msDS-LockoutObservationWindow:-18000000000
msDS-LockoutDuration:-18000000000
msDS-LockoutThreshold:0
msDS-PasswordSettingsPrecedence:20
msDS-PSOAppliesTo:CN=user1,CN=Users,DC=dc1,DC=contoso,DC=com
```

-jim

Comment: I did not implemented the Group Policy, the SysAdmins did that, but they only can show me where it is, in the Group Policy Management tool, not in the AD structure.
Regarding to your answer, the `CN=Password Settings Container` has a PSO in it, but it's not the one set for all users, it's only applies to a given group members.

Comment: I asked about the question you raised, and it seems the password policy is set to the Default Domain Policy, some kind of pre-server2008 way, but the `CN=Default Domain Policy,CN=System[...]` doeas not have `msDS-MaximumPasswordAge` attribute, and the `maxPwdAge` is not set.